# How to create dummy values with keys + array php

Tags: php, arrays

how to create dummy data based on what we give number like this format

for example when i give $var=2, so it will create two, when i give $var=100, it will create 100 like this using arrays in php

```
create like this based on number given, give 2 create like this
    [{"email":"test@test.com"},{"email":"test@test.com"}]
```

give 4 create like this

```
[{"email":"test@test.com"},{"email":"test@test.com"},{"email":"test@test.com"},{"email":"test@test.com"}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill):

```
$emails = array_fill(0, 100, 'test@test.com');
```

With your structure it is:

```
$emails = array_fill(0, 100, ['email' => 'test@test.com']);
```

Comment: Oh wow. Again an array function I have to use more often. 7+ years PHP and still new functions ^^

Answer (score 0):

Well, use a loop with as many circles as you need.
And inside the loop, create your email addresses.

Like a so:

```
$amount = 100;
$emails = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
    $emails[] = ['email' => 'test@test.com' ];
}
```

And then json encode it to get your expected output:

```
$emailJSON = json_encode($emails);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<?php
    $dummy = array();
    $dummyAmount = 100;

    for($i = 0; $i < $dummyAmount; $i++){
        $dummy[] = array("email" => "test@test.com");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = [];
$var = 100;
for( $i = 0; $i < $var; ++$i ) {
    $a[] = [
        'email' => 'test@test.com'
    ];
}

$json = json_encode($a)
```